# How can I redirect to my app - not deployed

Tags: flutter, redirect, spotify

I'm trying to make an integration between my app and spotify's API. So far I accomplished the token response and GET'S requests with it. But, there is a few endpoints that demand a higher authentication and the request demands a redirect uri as a parameter (see [link](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/)). How can I redirect to my flutter APP? I see a lot of examples showing the localhost, I'm not sure that's the case for mobile apps though.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?